# Bash script gets printed instead of being executed

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh, apt

This question is similar to this one: https://serverfault.com/questions/342697/prevent-sudo-apt-get-etc-from-swallowing-pasted-input-to-stdin but the answer is not satisfying (appending `&&` to each line of bash script is not elegant) and does not explain why some users can paste/execute multiple subsequent `apt-get install -y` commands and others can't because stdout is swollen by the next command.

I have a script `my_script.sh`:

```
sudo apt-get install -y graphicsmagick
sudo apt-get install -y libgraphicsmagick++1-dev
...
```

It can have only two lines or more of `sudo apt-get install` stuff. The libraries (graphicsmagick, etc.) doesn't matter, it can be any library.

When I copy this script and paste it's contents to bash or just execute it like this:

```
cat my_script.sh | sudo -i bash
```

then for some reason only the first line (graphicsmagick) gets executed and the rest is just printed to the console. It happens only with `sudo apt-get install -y`, other scripts, which doesn't contain this command behave normally.

If I change `bash` to `sh` (which is `dash`) I get expected behaviour:

```
cat my_script.sh | sudo -i sh
```

Can you explain **why** this happens?

When answering, can you please avoid this questions/comments:

1. Why are you doing it this way?
2. Piping to your bash is not safe
3. Some other aspects are not safe or hackish

I just want to know why `bash` doesn't work as I would expect and `sh` does.

PS. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, sh is dash as you can see here:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/tmp$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Feb 19  2014 /bin/sh -> dash
```

Comment: How do you know `sh` is `dash`? `ls -l /bin/sh` should tell you. What OS are you using?

Comment: @KeithThompson - yes, it's dash, ubuntu 14.04, quiestion edited.

Comment: Probably not relevant to your problem, but you shouldn't need to use `sudo` both in your script and when invoking `bash` or `sh`.

Comment: @KeithThompson - agree but should it cause any problems?

Comment: Not that I know of (invoking `sudo` as `root` should be ok) -- but this problem is weird enough that it might be worth trying without the extra `sudo`.

Comment: I would suspect the user's bash profile to be causing it. Try removing `-i` in the command to see if it works. The `-i` tells sudo to source the user's bash profile, removing it effectively stops sudo from sourcing the profile.

Comment: @alvits adding `-i` doesn't work.

Comment: @KeithThompson - removing inner `sudo` doesn't work.

Comment: This could have been reduced to a script file `sudo apt-get -y install graphicsmagick<NEWLINE>sudo apt-get -y install libgraphicsmagick++1-dev` getting executed differently by `cat tmp.sh | bash` and `cat tmp.sh | dash`. This is what a *minimal* example is about, and doesn't require people to either sudo-execute a downloaded script or reducing the problem themselves. Verified this on Mint 17; it seems like `bash` is somehow feeding the rest of `stdin` to `apt-get` **before** the `-y` option kicks in. Strange...

Comment: @DevSolar - agree, question edited.

Comment: Just a blind guess, but it might help http://askubuntu.com/questions/61719/why-the-software-center-doesnt-allow-multiple-downloads Couldn't there be a problem with simultaneous use of apt-get? Don't throw rocks please..

Comment: @mnowotka - we already knew that adding `-i` will not work. That was in your original code. What I suggested was to remove it. But I guess Tomas Szuba already has an explanation, so no need to test it.

Answer (score 1):

Bash and dash simply behave different when using -i flag.
Bash always goes to interactive mode even when stdin is not a terminal.
Dash on the other hand will not go into interactive mode, even with -i flag.

Answer (score 0):

Probably need the `-s` option

> If the `-s` option is present, or if no arguments remain after option
>   processing, then commands are read from the standard input. This option allows
>   the positional parameters to be set when invoking an interactive shell.

[Bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

```
curl -s http://foo.com/bar.sh | sudo -i bash -s
```

[Example](http://rvm.io)